# Android listview (setOnItemClickListener) Item to check and uncheck the checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I ve implemented listView with LargeText(for title), SmallText(for detail) and CheckBox, Now what I want is that if user click the listView Item then checkbox of that item should get toggle and I also want to disable the click on checkbox itself so it could be handled by listView Item only.

Regards
MGD

Comment: I ve extended baseAdapter, the things are on the screen yet the functionality that I ve mentioned above is stalled as no idea yet produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve end up with the following code is working for me

```
listView[0].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                    cBox.toggle();

            }
```

}

Regards
MGD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the check event and *imitate* toggle on checkboxes, I think you are going to have to;

- Detect selected item via [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)
- Change the model bound to `ListView`
- Reset the adapter / bind it again for changes to take affect.

Are you sure about this approach tho? I had pretty much the same design for one of my apps and it was just confusing the users. You might wanna use a *tick* icon or smth otherwise these dumb users will try to click on the checkbox.

Good luck.